# Conditional SQL query with count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Would it be possible to have the following:

In case `assignments.customer_id = customers.id` is `NULL` the query would be

```
$query  = "
SELECT customers.*
  FROM customers
 WHERE customers.active = 0
ORDER 
    BY customers.event_date DESC
";
```

When it does exist it would become:

```
$query  = "
SELECT customers.* 
  FROM customers
     , assignments
 WHERE customers.active = 0
   AND NOT assignments.status = 5
   AND assignments.customer_id = customers.id
 ORDER BY customers.event_date DESC
";
```

Or should this be done in separate queries with an if statement in PHP?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: TBH, I'm not grasping the question and is unclear for me; it's the *"When it does exist it would become"* that I don't understand. You've been given an answer below if you haven't seen it. If that doesn't solve what you're asking, you should post a comment under it.

Comment: I'm with @Fred-ii- here. I don't think that I understand the question. Or, maybe I do, and the person who wrote the below answer didn't understand it? As I see it, if customer_id == null, you want to run those four lines. If customer_id != null, you want to run the six lines?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the logic correctly, you want inactive customers that have no assignment with a status of 5:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM assignments a
                  WHERE a.customer_id = c.id AND a.status = 5
                 )
       c.active = 0
ORDER BY c.event_date DESC;
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick

```
$query  = "SELECT COUNT(customers.id) AS customer_count ";
$query .= "FROM customers "; 
$query .= "LEFT JOIN assignments ON customers.id = assignments.customer_id ";
$query .= "WHERE customers.id IS NULL ";
$query .= "AND assignments.customer_id IS NULL ";
$query .= "AND customers.active = 0 ";
$query .= "AND assignments.status != 5 ";
$query .= "ORDER BY customers.event_date DESC";
```

Comment: Left join x where x is the same as inner join x